# TreeView's Object binding to another view

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a requirements to implement in one of our application which are listed below. I have a query how to achieve this in WPF.

1. I have main WPF window which is divided into Tree View on left side and Form with some text boxes and combo boxes, check boxes on right side.
2. I want to populate the Right side form with respective values from the Object stored in Tag value of Tree Node.
3. Whenever I click particular node on tree view, The Form fields on Right side will display the contents of  the object store in its Tag value which eventually will be updated if I do some modifications in Right side Form fields.

Can anybody give a link to sample application?

Answer (score 0):

Your question relate to a very fundamental concept in WPF which is the [(Data) Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx). Please start with this article.

Please note that putting the interesting/editable object in a `Tag` property of `TreeViewItem` is a very bad idea for the UI design. The `Tag` property is easily accessible from the code, but from the UI it will be quite tough/complext to bind to - all because the `TreeView` itself exposes only a `SelectedItem/SelectedIndex` properties that returns usually **the data items**, not the `TreeViewItems`.

Please play with this example:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TreeView x:Name="twi">
        <TreeViewItem Tag="one" Header="111">
            <TextBlock Text="First" />
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Tag="two" Header="222">
            <TextBlock Text="Second" />
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Tag="three" Header="333">
            <TextBlock Text="Third" />
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="The text:" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=twi, Path=SelectedItem}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=twi, Path=SelectedItem.Tag}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=twi, Path=SelectedItem.Tag.Name}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=twi, Path=SelectedItem.Tag.Surname}" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

This is the whole sample, just put it anywhere. On the left side are items, on the right are some labels. As you click through the TreeView, the labels will update and show what is selected and also its `Tag` property. Of course, the TAGs are set to simple strings, so .Name and .Surname will display nothing. However if you set TAGs to some data objects, it would display properly. Note that if you click on TWI it will do what you expect, but if you click on a **child** of the TWI, it will not - all in all, it is the child text is selected!

You will need to be very careful on what you put in the treeview, and very careful about what/where you put the Tags' values. This is not a good approach. More typically, you'd:

```
public class Person
{
    // properties
    public string Name { .... }
    public string Surname { ... }

    public List<Person> Subordinates { .... }
}

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TreeView x:Name="twi">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Subordinates}">
                <TextBlock>
                    <Run Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <Run Text=" " />
                    <Run Text="{Binding Surname}" />
                </TextBlock>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="The selected person:" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=twi, Path=SelectedItem.Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=twi, Path=SelectedItem.Surname, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

And of course, create some example data and provide it to the treeView as its ItemsSource.
This way, the TreeView will create the items automatically, apply the templates, and every on every click, the SelectedItem provide you not with `TreeViewItem`s, but - with `Person`, that is directly editable. Thus, on the right side of the window, simple binding to `SelectedItem.Name` will "just work", and if you make it 2-way, it will directly update the Person.

disclaimer: I have not run the codes. There may be bugs and typos. The code is just to show the general idea.

Comment: Hi Quetzalcoatl, Thanks for such nice sample. Will test this and accept as answer.